# Why can't I use a variable as a ID selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for being a jQuery noob but I'm not understanding why I can't place a variable as a selector name? If I do an alert it works fine, but not when I try to modify the contents of an id:

```
'success': function () {
        var varpk = $(this).editable().data('pk');
        //alert('#test' + varpk);
        var spanid = '#test' + varpk;
        //alert(spanid);
        $(spanid).html(varpk);
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a variable as a selector. The selector you are using must not match the element you are targeting.

Comment: As @KevinB says, what you have should work fine. My guess is there's a problem with your AJAX request and the `success` handler isn't being hit. Check the console for errors.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/maD7c/1/ Works here, you might be getting wrong selector

Comment: It should work fine as long as you are able to select the element. Check the value of `spanid` and see if such an element exists in dom. Alert this to verify `alert($(spanid).length)`

Comment: @JohnRiselvato Why? Plus then the name is wrong. I have no issues with either form.

Comment: In addition to all suggestions made above, also make sure the variable `varpk` is a primary data type. If it's not a `string`, `number` or `boolean` you'll need to convert via `toString()` to concatenate it in a "clean" manner.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not the case since alert() works with it. The value displays properly when I display in an alert, it's just not getting passed when I use it as the selector.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why this is being voted down. I see it as a legitimate question, especially when an alert() displays my expected values. Don't vote down unless you can provide a reason for this being a stupid question AND back it up.

Comment: @DonavonYelton While I didn't vote down, the bottom line is that there's no reason a variable can't be used as a selector--it's quite common, and works just fine. This means there's something else going on, which nobody can help with, because we only see code that is more or less guaranteed to work as advertised.

Comment: @Vega If I check the length of spanid it comes out as 0, but as stated, if I place spanid in an alert() it displays properly.

Comment: @SuviVignarajah Am I not converting it to a string in line #4?

Comment: @KevinB You had the right answer, it was literally this. I failed to add the variable in my PHP code to the end of the ID. Stupid stupid stupid...off to hide my head in a hole now...

Comment: @DonavonYelton if the variable is a type `object`, you'll get `[object Object]` appended to the string, not an actual value. But seeing your comments that you see your expected results in an alert message, there is clearly something else wrong. What do you get when you just alert `$(spanid)`? If it's an empty object then the element you're targeting doesn't exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure the ID exists, it should work form your code there.

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cmWfV/):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var id = '#' + 'asdf';
    $(id).html('fdsa');
}, 2000);
```

PS: I believe your $(this) is not returning what you think it should, unless you really want to target the context of the callback.

Comment: This is not really an answer. It should have been a comment.

Comment: @Lix Debugging is the answer ;-) But OK, added a working example.

Comment: If debugging is the answer then we should automatically add it to every question asked here. It's not an answer at all. It's great advice, yea... but not an answer.

Comment: Your example obfuscates the problem, and is little more than saying "it works fine", which is what everyone already said in the comments.

Comment: A hint that you might not be posting an answer is if your answer contains 3 more questions :)

Comment: @schlingel Yes I'm sure everything is being returned properly because I can place the values in an alert() and I get the expected result.

Comment: @DonavonYelton Than the element doesn't exist with the given ID. Just return the ID in the console and try to run $('#yourid') in the browser console. (e.g. in chrome it's right click, inspect element and click on the console tab.) There seem to be differences in the ID you use and the id which is there.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should ask clarifying questions in comments to the question. It's a bit clumsy-looking to do so by editing them into/out of the answer, and it definitely makes the answer not look like an answer to begin with. It looks like you ended up with the essence of an answer here, so I'm just going to remove the questions from it. If you still need to ask those, please do so using comments. Thanks!